# PowerShell scripts only run new code when renamed

Tags: powershell

I'm currently writing some PS scripts to help me with some tasks at my job. This has been going great, but I've noticed something very wrong when I'm attempting to make changes to a script.

In ISE, everything works fine. When I make changes and run the script, the changes are reflected and it does what it has been told to. However, if I run the script from Explorer (by double-clicking on the script) it runs what appears to be an old version of the script without any of the changes I've made.

If I rename the file to something else, it runs the updated code. So I edit in the renamed file. Except I have to rename it AGAIN to make changes. I ensured there were no powershell.exe processes lingering about that might be affecting things.

Is there some weird script cache in PS that I don't know about and can't find info about?

Comment: Might be an "Explorer cache" thing. Try and refresh the explorer window before launching the modified script (press F5 or Right-Click -> "Refresh")

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice. I also tried stopping and restarting explorer.exe, also no result.

Comment: I wasnt aware of a cache thing that would cause this issue. Do the file timestamps not change then when you save? If you close and reopen ISE you can get the _new_ file opened again. This one might be hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are these scripts being saved in a folder on a server? And is it available offline?

Comment: Why not do all your development in ISE and not worry about using Explorer until everything is working? Alternatively you could write your script so that the first thing it does is read itself into a variable and then execute the variable with Invoke-Expression. This gets around any funky Explorer behavior. You could use a global variable as a switch so script won't infinitely loop. Double clicking in Explorer the variable is not set, but set variable before calling Invoke-Expression, so second time through it doesn't try to read itself again.